# How handles keyup event a input type="text"

Tags: angular, components, angular6

I need to take what the user writes in input, so I do this ( in my html page):

```
<label>Filter Name</label>
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="onKeyEnter()" name="book_name"/>
```

and in my .ts i do:

```
onKeyEnter(){
    console.log("Home");
  }
```

The problem is the console it doesn't print console. Anyone cna help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to handle keyup you can use **`(keyup)`** instead. **`keyup.enter`** works only for Enter key

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyEnter()" name="book_name"/>
```

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdel2t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)